# Android studio button has no onclick option

Tags: java, android, mobile

I'm currently learning to make apps in android studio.
When I drag a button object into the activity_main.xml,it does not show me the "onclick" option under the "Declare Attributes".

The only error I'm getting is :

> Render problem   Couldn't resolve resource @color/colorAccent

I dont think it has anything to do with my problem but still...

Any help would be appriciated,thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@color/colorAccent points to a problem with the colour "colorAccent" in your Colors.xml, In android Onclick etc. must be coded manually unlike Xcode where you drag and it generates, [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button) is an article for android buttons

Answer (score 0):

Hi it will be helpful if you will upload here you'r xml file.

In general the "Declare Attributes" will show you only the attributes that you declared on in the xml file.

In example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="135dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="389dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[for this xml file you will get only this "Declare Attributes"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2SAV.png)
And now if you add:

```
 android:onClick="doSomthing"
```

to the button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="135dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="389dp" 
    android:onClick="doSomthing"
    />
```

you will now see the "onClick" attribute on the "Declare Attributes"

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aADof.png)

you can scroll down to "All Attributes" and see them all.
or just write the attribute you want in the xml file as i did.

hope this is helped

Comment: Thank you! could you do that in older versions of AS? I mean did the option onClick was visible? because in the course he has that option from the start.

Comment: I don't know if it visible in other versions from the start, but you can always add attributes and object to the xml file directly. The xml file is what the program will read and the scene builder is just to make it easyer.